# Error: int cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java

I'm getting the "int cannot be dereferenced" error for the following code. Any help is appreciated. Thanks:

```
public int value()
{
int total = 0;

**for (int i = 0; i < wallet.length; i++);**

total += wallet[i];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `;` represents an **empty statement**. When you don't include curly braces `{}` to delimite the `for` body, its body will be the next statement. In this case, this stament is an empty statement. Therefore, the line

```
total += wallet[i];
```

is outside the scope of the `for` loop, so you can't use `i`.

**How to fix this?** 
Just delete the semi-colon `;`

```
for (int i = 0; i < wallet.length; i++);
                                       ^---- delete
```

Answer (score 0):

That's why it's highly recommended to *always* have curly braces, even for one statement.

Your `for` loop is like writing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < wallet.length; i++) { }
```

Which does nothing. Remove the semicolon as Christian already told you, but remember to always have `{` and `}`, even for one line code inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Semicolon `;

Your code :

`for (int i = 0; i < wallet.length; i++);` Remove `;`

`total += wallet[i];`

Write like

`for (int i = 0; i < wallet.length; i++)`
`{
total += wallet[i];
}`